# JSON.parse is giving an "undefined" object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, object-literal

I tried to parse this string :

```
[{"ZoneId": "1", "0": "1", "ZoneX": "29", "1": "29", "ZoneY": "27", "2":     "27", "ZoneWidth": "76", "3": "76", "ZoneHeight": "61", "4": "61", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"},
{"ZoneId": "2", "0": "2", "ZoneX": "382", "1": "382", "ZoneY": "226", "2": "226", "ZoneWidth": "-117", "3": "-117", "ZoneHeight": "98", "4": "98", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "3", "6": "3"},
{"ZoneId": "3", "0": "3", "ZoneX": "108", "1": "108", "ZoneY": "74", "2": "74", "ZoneWidth": "363", "3": "363", "ZoneHeight": "83", "4": "83", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"}]
```

Using JSON.parse() on this string show me "undefined" in the console. According to [this site](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com), my json is valid. It comes from a json_encode given by a php function.

If it can help, the final goal is to loop through this json array. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

I realized that my error was in fact a scope issue using literal functions. Yes, I'm a bit stupid sometimes. Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Make sure that all the `"` are properly escaped when you input it to the parse.

Comment: Where is the string? How are you getting the object? How are you parsing it? You lack details

Comment: JSFiddle showing that the above does in-fact work fine with `JSON.parse`. http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/sqwyxoo5/

Comment: JSON.parse() parses a 'string' as JSON. If you need to parse it with JSON.parse, I think an easy way is to enclose it with single quotes, using double quotes will not work as the content contains unescaped double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no `String`, its a valid JSON which you can use in JavaScript:

```
var jsonData = [{"ZoneId": "1", "0": "1", "ZoneX": "29", "1": "29", "ZoneY": "27", "2":     "27", "ZoneWidth": "76", "3": "76", "ZoneHeight": "61", "4": "61", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"},
{"ZoneId": "2", "0": "2", "ZoneX": "382", "1": "382", "ZoneY": "226", "2": "226", "ZoneWidth": "-117", "3": "-117", "ZoneHeight": "98", "4": "98", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "3", "6": "3"},
{"ZoneId": "3", "0": "3", "ZoneX": "108", "1": "108", "ZoneY": "74", "2": "74", "ZoneWidth": "363", "3": "363", "ZoneHeight": "83", "4": "83", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"}];

for(index in jsonData) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData[index]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your string is not json object
but
it is an json array object (check out the square brackets).
so to get the value you must run it into "for" or "each" or ...
.each example below
pass the string to variable and then ;

```
var obj=[{"ZoneId": "1", "0": "1", "ZoneX": "29", "1": "29", "ZoneY": "27", "2":     "27", "ZoneWidth": "76", "3": "76", "ZoneHeight": "61", "4": "61", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"},
{"ZoneId": "2", "0": "2", "ZoneX": "382", "1": "382", "ZoneY": "226", "2": "226", "ZoneWidth": "-117", "3": "-117", "ZoneHeight": "98", "4": "98", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "3", "6": "3"},
{"ZoneId": "3", "0": "3", "ZoneX": "108", "1": "108", "ZoneY": "74", "2": "74", "ZoneWidth": "363", "3": "363", "ZoneHeight": "83", "4": "83", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"}]

            jQuery.each(obj, function(key,value) {
                alert(value.ZoneId);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your having a return like this

```
var json_string =  "[{"0":"1","1":"29","2":"27","3":"76","4":"61","5":"46","6":"2","ZoneId":"1","ZoneX":"29","ZoneY":"27","ZoneWidth":"76","ZoneHeight":"61","ZoneImage":"46","ZonePointTo":"2"},{"0":"2","1":"382","2":"226","3":"-117","4":"98","5":"46","6":"3","ZoneId":"2","ZoneX":"382","ZoneY":"226","ZoneWidth":"-117","ZoneHeight":"98","ZoneImage":"46","ZonePointTo":"3"},{"0":"3","1":"108","2":"74","3":"363","4":"83","5":"46","6":"2","ZoneId":"3","ZoneX":"108","ZoneY":"74","ZoneWidth":"363","ZoneHeight":"83","ZoneImage":"46","ZonePointTo":"2"}]"
```

then you can use the JSON.parse() function

and it will decode the stringify json data

and it will return you

```
 [{"ZoneId": "1", "0": "1", "ZoneX": "29", "1": "29", "ZoneY": "27", "2":     "27", "ZoneWidth": "76", "3": "76", "ZoneHeight": "61", "4": "61", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"},
{"ZoneId": "2", "0": "2", "ZoneX": "382", "1": "382", "ZoneY": "226", "2": "226", "ZoneWidth": "-117", "3": "-117", "ZoneHeight": "98", "4": "98", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "3", "6": "3"},
{"ZoneId": "3", "0": "3", "ZoneX": "108", "1": "108", "ZoneY": "74", "2": "74", "ZoneWidth": "363", "3": "363", "ZoneHeight": "83", "4": "83", "ZoneImage": "46", "5": "46", "ZonePointTo": "2", "6": "2"}]
```

since the return is already a json object then no need to use JSON.parse();